# is there any way to not installing packages on Google Colab every time?

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

some packages like numpy are installed as default in Google Colab. is there any way to not installing new packages and make it default just like numpy?

Comment: If you install binary package, it's not that slow. It's slow only when the packages need to be compiled from source. So, a solution is to use pre-compiled binary package or to compile it once before install the binary many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's currently no way for users to choose additional packages to install by default.